# Java Sorting Algorithms

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have a class called ThreeSorts.java
The aim is to generate a random arraylist of size n - this works.

Then display the array - this works.

Then I have to prove that these sorting algorithms work, however when I pass the random generated array into one of the sorts like SortA(a);
and then display the array it does not get sorted the output is the same:

```
Generated ArrayList : (153),(209),(167),(117),(243),(67),(0),(148),(39),(188),

SortA ArrayList : (153),(209),(167),(117),(243),(67),(0),(148),(39),(188),
```

ThreeSorts.java:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ThreeSorts 
{
    private static ArrayList<Integer> CopyArray(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> resa = new ArrayList<Integer>(a.size());
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i) resa.add(a.get(i));
        return(resa);
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> SortA(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
        int n = a.size(),i;
        boolean noswaps = false;

        while (noswaps == false)
        {
            noswaps = true;
            for(i=0;i<n-1;++i)
            {
                if (array.get(i) < array.get(i+1))
                {
                    Integer temp = array.get(i);
                    array.set(i,array.get(i+1));
                    array.set(i+1,temp);
                    noswaps = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return(array);
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> SortB(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
        Integer[] zero = new Integer[a.size()];
        Integer[] one = new Integer[a.size()];
        int i,b;
        Integer x,p;
        //Change from 8 to 32 for whole integers - will run 4 times slower
        for(b=0;b<8;++b)
        {
            int zc = 0;
            int oc = 0;
            for(i=0;i<array.size();++i)
            {
                x = array.get(i);
                p = 1 << b;
                if ((x & p) == 0)
                {
                    zero[zc++] = array.get(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    one[oc++] = array.get(i);
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<oc;++i) array.set(i,one[i]);
            for(i=0;i<zc;++i) array.set(i+oc,zero[i]);
        }
        return(array);
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> SortC(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
        SortC(array,0,array.size()-1);
        return(array);
    }
    public static void SortC(ArrayList<Integer> array,int first,int last)
    {
        if (first < last)
        {
           int pivot = PivotList(array,first,last);
           SortC(array,first,pivot-1);
           SortC(array,pivot+1,last);
        }   
    }
    private static void Swap(ArrayList<Integer> array,int a,int b)
    {
        Integer temp = array.get(a);
        array.set(a,array.get(b));
        array.set(b,temp);
    }
    private static int PivotList(ArrayList<Integer> array,int first,int last)
    {
        Integer PivotValue = array.get(first);
        int PivotPoint = first;
        for(int index=first+1;index<=last;++index)
        {
            if (array.get(index) > PivotValue)
            {
                PivotPoint = PivotPoint+1;
                Swap(array,PivotPoint,index);
            }
        }
        Swap(array,first,PivotPoint);
        return(PivotPoint);
    }
    /////////////My Code////////////////
    public static ArrayList<Integer> randomArrayList(int n)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            list.add(random.nextInt(255));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void showArray(ArrayList<Integer> a) { 
        for (Iterator<Integer> iter = a.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
        {
            Integer x = (Integer)iter.next();
            System.out.print(("("+x + ")"));
            System.out.print(",");
            //System.out.print(GetAge());
            //System.out.print(") ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void test(int n) {
        //int n = 13;
        ArrayList<Integer> a = randomArrayList(n);
        System.out.println("Generated ArrayList : ");
        showArray(a);
        System.out.println("SortA ArrayList : ");
        SortA(a);
        showArray(a);
    }


}
```

Test is called in main like this `ThreeSorts.test(10);`

Why is it not getting sorted even tho the random array is passed and there are no errors?

Comment: Try a = SortA(a);

Comment: You are printing the original array but sorting a copy of it.

Comment: You’re not storing the return value of SortA in a, thus the original value of a will still be there and you’ll be printing your original input twice.

Comment: Try to debug your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code you are only testing `SortA` which reads:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
    ...
    return(array);
```

so actually it is taking a copy of your array, sorting it, and then returning you the sorted array.

So when you test it, instead of using:

```
SortA(a);
```

you need to use

```
a = SortA(a);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer this was s silly overlook of mine thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The type of data your function `SortA` returns is `ArrayList<Integer>`, which means it returns an array list of integers. You need to change the line `SortA(a);` to `a = SortA(a);`: this way `a` variable will receive the results of this function's work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the returned value, otherwise a will not be sorted in test method. Change the way you call SortA(a) to:

```
static void test(int n) {
    //int n = 13;
    ArrayList<Integer> a = randomArrayList(n);
    System.out.println("Generated ArrayList : ");
    showArray(a);
    System.out.println("SortA ArrayList : ");
    a = SortA(a);
    showArray(a);
}
```

Comment: Probably he should have a second variable for the returned array, since his sorting methods aren't modifying the `a` array. Declare a new variable `ArrayList<Integer> sortedArray;` Then, `sortedArray = SortA(a);` Otherwise, when he tests `SortB` and `SortC`, he'll be passing them an array that's already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the method `SortA(a);` just use `Collections.sort(a);` inside static block. Like

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = randomArrayList(n);
    System.out.println("Generated ArrayList : ");
    showArray(a);
    System.out.println("SortA ArrayList : ");
    Collections.sort(a);
    showArray(a);
```

Thats it.

Comment: He has to test his methods, not Collections.sort

Comment: so he should store the sorted data into some variable or he can use 
    a = SortA(a);